# How to loop until element clickable

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, python-webbrowser

i am using python selenium chrome driver and i am stuck at this.

How can i loop this code until one of the elements is clickable?

Like if its finally clickable it should get clicked and print ("clickable") and if its still not clickable it should print ("Not Clickable")

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//BUTTON[@type='submit'[text()='Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 150).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-modal__content")))
```

Comment: Clarify your question. Do you need to click the first of these two elements when it becomes clickable?

Comment: Oh sorry, did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your use of uppercase button is correct. Use the same syntax as in html.

One more thing: check your xpath with text():
It should be: `//button[@type='submit' and text()='Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen']`

Also, the general case for such loop in the case of one element is:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
while True:
    try:
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit' and text()='Zum Warenkorb hinzufügen']")))
        print("clickable")
        element.click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break
```

Comment: Im getting this error:  except TimeoutException:
NameError: name 'TimeoutException' is not defined

Comment: Add from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException